# writing data into a file

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to write data into a file. This is the script. Its easy and not correct too. But Pls help me to get the output.

```
#!bin/ksh
DATE=date +'%m/%d/%Y'_$CNTR_SEQ
file1=$1 # Signifies DATE config file
file2=$2 # Signifies MONT config file
file3=$3 # Signifies YEAR config file
file4=$4 # Signifies SEQN config file
file5=$5 # Signifies FILETYPE config 
file6=$6 # Signifies CNTR1 config file
file7=$7 # Signifies CNTR2 config file


for CNTR_DATE in {0..100}; do
    for CNTR_SEQ in {1..4}; do
        NEXT_DATE=$(date +%m-%d-%Y_$CNTR_SEQ -d "$DATE + $CNTR_DATE day")
        echo $NEXT_DATE
        if [ -f $5=TST ]; then
            printf "$3-$2-$1|$4|\n0000000|0\n00000" > echo TST_$NEXT_DATE.dat 
            # This is the content of file.This should be the file creation with
            # that date's name pattern.The contents of file is been written into 
            # a specific name pattern. Is this correct?
        fi
        cat /MYDIR/$echo
        # A file is creating in the  MYDIR /FILE_NAME path.
        exit(0)
    done
done
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting. It looks like your question text got caught in the middle of your script somehow. Please pay attention to formatting, it's really really difficult to read poorly formatted questions.

Comment: You don't seem to have set $DATE anywhere.

Comment: Also, you don't have a closing } to match the opening one on the line before the "if" statement.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Please find my code now. Will this work?

Comment: +1 for making code changes in your question, rather than in the comments! ..... While `exit(0)` will not blow up, you only need `exit` or `exit 0`. Also I don't see that you ever use all of the `file1=$1` variables AND  what do you intend with `cat /MYDIR/$echo`? a. don't use a cmd name as a variable, AND b. I don't see that you've set a variable `echo` anyway. Finally, you're shooting your self in the foot (in the long term) by naming your files with `%m-%d-%Y`, use `%Y-%m-%d` and the files will automatically organize themselves in time order! Good luck!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `exit` statement? You really want to quit after the first iteration? (Besides the fact that you should get rid of the parens)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to divine what you're trying to accomplish. Perhaps:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for days in {0..100}; do
    future_date=$(date -d "+$days days" +%m-%d-%Y)
    for seq in {1..4}; do
        file="/mydir/TST_${future_date}_${seq}.dat"
        if [ $5 = "TST" ]; then
            printf "$3-$2-$1|$4|\n0000000|0\n00000" > "$file"
        fi
    done
done
```

Avoid using all upper case variable names.  One day you will use a variable named PATH and then wonder why you start seeing "command not found" errors.

I fully agree with the comment "use %Y-%m-%d"